# How to show images from API in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, alamofire, swifty-json

So, I need parse images from JSON and show them in `CollectionView`. I use a few frameworks like this: Alamofire, AlamofireImage, SwiftyJson.

```
My JSON is here:
```

```
    {
    "data" : [
        {
          "id" : "Un5PeP1wG99QI",
          "rating" : "g",
          "trending_datetime" : "2016-11-11 22:00:01",
          "import_datetime" : "2016-08-05 23:33:46",
          "bitly_gif_url" : "http:\/\/gph.is\/2aXBfTM",
          "url" : "http:\/\/giphy.com\/gifs\/muslim-american-Un5PeP1wG99QI",
          "content_url" : "",
          "type" : "gif",
          "source" : "http:\/\/www.buzzfeed.com\/regajha\/a-group-of-muslim-hipsters-made-a-video-thats-really-really",
          "source_tld" : "www.buzzfeed.com",
          "source_post_url" : "http:\/\/www.buzzfeed.com\/regajha\/a-group-of-muslim-hipsters-made-a-video-thats-really-really",
          "is_indexable" : 0,
          "slug" : "muslim-american-Un5PeP1wG99QI",
          "bitly_url" : "http:\/\/gph.is\/2aXBfTM",
          "username" : "",
          "images" : {
            "fixed_height_small" : {
              "height" : "100",
              "mp4_size" : "10981",
              "width" : "179",
              "size" : "139756",
              "mp4" : "http:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/100.mp4",
              "webp" : "http:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/100.webp",
              "webp_size" : "44776",
              "url" : "http:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/100.gif"
            },
            "downsized_large" : {
              "size" : "799980",
              "url" : "http:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/giphy.gif",
              "width" : "500",
              "height" : "280"
            },
            "looping" : {
              "mp4" : "http:\/\/media.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/giphy-loop.mp4"
            },
            "preview" : {
              "height" : "280",
              "mp4" : "http:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/giphy-preview.mp4",
              "mp4_size" : "48074",
              "width" : "500"
            },
            "downsized_small" : {
              "height" : "280",
              "mp4" : "http:\/\/media1.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/giphy-downsized-small.mp4",
              "mp4_size" : "48074",
              "width" : "500"
            },
            "fixed_width" : {
              "height" : "112",
              "mp4_size" : "11866",
              "width" : "200",
              "size" : "170452",
              "mp4" : "http:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/200w.mp4",
              "webp" : "http:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/200w.webp",
              "webp_size" : "50438",
              "url" : "http:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/200w.gif"
            }
      ]
    }
```

**My `ViewController` is here:**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
import SwiftyJSON

class MainViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var imagesArray = [[String : AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadImages()
    }


    // MARK: Cell
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagesArray.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        //let url = NSURL(string: imagesArray[indexPath.row])
        //cell.imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: url)
        return cell
    }

    func loadImages() {
        Alamofire.request("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC").responseJSON {(responseData) -> Void in
            if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let responseJsonData = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                print(responseJsonData)
                if let resData = responseJsonData["data"].arrayObject {
                    self.imagesArray = resData as! [[String : AnyObject]]
                }
                if self.imagesArray.count > 0 {
                    self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My `CollectionViewCell`:**

```
    import UIKit

    class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    }
```

Please, help me. Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem with your code above

Comment: @Enix in function loadImage() I'm writing next: self.imagesArray = resData as! [[String : AnyObject]] in function cellForItemAt I'm writing: let url = NSURL(string: imagesArray[indexPath.row]) and I get error : "Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]' to expected argument type 'String' "

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function to iterate each object in the `data` array, and extract the `url` from `fixed_height_small` object under `images` array. (suppose you need to extract `url` from `fixed_height_small`)

Your json dictionary liked this after parsed:

```
["data": 
     [
        ["images": 
           ["fixed_height_small": 
                ["url": "http:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/Un5PeP1wG99QI\/100.gif"]
           ]
        ]
     ]
]
```

example code:

```
func loadImages() {
        Alamofire.request("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC")
            .responseJSON {(responseData) -> Void in
            if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let responseJsonData = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                print(responseJsonData)
                self.imagesArray = responseJsonData["data"].arrayValue.map({
                    (item) -> NSURL in
                    NSURL(string: item["images"]["fixed_height_small"]["url"].stringValue)!
                })

                if self.imagesArray.count > 0 {
                    self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load url in imageview by using [iOSDevCenters+GIF.swift file](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/08/load-gif-image-in-swift_22.html)

here is sample code for the same:

```
let gifURL : String = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC"
let imgURL = UIImage.gifImageWithURL(gifURL)
let imgvwTemp = UIImageView(image: imageURL)
cell.imageView.image = imgvwTemp.image
```

Hope it'll help you :)